# Javascript int numbers addition problem

Tags: javascript

I have numbers in javascript from 01(int) to 09(int) and I want add 1(int) to each one.

For example:

```
01 + 1 = 2
02 + 1 = 3
```

But

```
08 + 1 = 1
09 + 1 = 1
```

I know the solution. I've defined them as float type.

**But I want to learn, what is the reason for this result?**

Thank you.

Comment: Dont use twitter abbreviations here. Reformat your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Javascript, like other languages, may treat numbers beginning with `0` as octal. That means only the digits 0 through 7 would be valid.

What seems to be happening is that `08` and `09` are being treated as octal but, because they have invalid characters, those characters are being silently ignored. So what you're actually calculating is `0 + 1`.

Alternatively, it may be that the entire `08` is being ignored and having `0` substituted for it.

The best way would be to try `028 + 1` and see if you get `3` or `1` (or possibly even `30` if the interpretation is *really* weird).

Comment: Arf you add me by few seconds pax ;-) and you writing style is a lot better ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Since you haven't specified the radix it is treated as octal numbers. `08` and `09` are not valid octal numbers.

```
parseInt(08,10) + 1;
```

will give you the correct result.

See **[parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/ParseInt)**

Comment: that fact that quotes aren't required kind of boggles the mind.

Answer (score 1):

This because if your do `09 + 1` the `09` is formated as octal (because of being prefixed by 0). Octal values go to 0 to 7, your code seems to prove that certain JavaScript engine convert 8 and 9 to invalid characters and just ignore them.

Yu shouldn't prefix by 0 your numbers if you don't want to use the octal (like using the normal decimal numbers).

See this page for [reference](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/octalsan.htm) and wikipedia for what is the [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal)

Answer (score 0):

As you may have seen from the answers above, you are having type-conflict. However, I thought I would also suggest the correct solution to your problem...

So as we know, 08 and 09 are treated as ocal in this example:

```
08 + 1 = 1
09 + 1 = 1
```

So you need to specify what they actually are:

```
parseInt("08", 10) + 1 = 1
parseInt("09", 10) + 1 = 1
```

Don't define them as a float if you want them to be integers.

Comment: You still need to specify the base: parseInt('08', 10) or you will still evaluate octal numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I just test the numbers, like

a= 08;
b= 1;
c= a+b;

It gives me exactly 9